# Combine Hash Tables With the Same Keys but Different Values in Powershell

Tags: powershell, key

Okay, I have some hash tables I need to combine using PowerShell. Here is an example of the format:

```
$table1 = @{"A" = "1,2";
            "B" = "3,4";
            "C" = "5,6"}

$table2 = @{"A" = "3";
            "B" = "5";
            "C" = "7"}
```

I need to combine the tables in order to create the following table:

```
$newTable = @{"A" = "1,2,3";
              "B" = "3,4,5";
              "C" = "5,6,7"}
```

Basically, the keys and values need to be compared. If the values are different, they needed to be added together. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
$table1 = @{"A" = "1,2";
            "B" = "3,4";
            "C" = "5,6"}

$table2 = @{"A" = "3";
            "B" = "5";
            "C" = "7"}

$ht = $table1.Clone()
$table2.GetEnumerator() | % {$ht[$_.Key] += ",$($_.Value)"}
$ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
C                              5,6,7
A                              1,2,3
B                              3,4,5
```

Comment: Well the two approaches aren't exactly functionally equivalent. The approach I propose pulls in everything from $table2 - not just the KV pairs that match keys with $table1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetEnumerator()` method to loop through the values like below.

This will become much more complicated if you have uneven key distribution (some exist only in `$table1` and others only in `$table2`) but it works for your example scenario.

```
$table1 = @{"A" = "1,2";
            "B" = "3,4";
            "C" = "5,6"}

$table2 = @{"A" = "3";
            "B" = "5";
            "C" = "7"}


$NewTable = @{}

$table1.GetEnumerator() | 
%   {
    $NewTable.Add($_.Key, ("$($_.Value),$($table2[$_.Key])"))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$table1 = @{"A" = "1,2";
            "B" = "3,4";
            "C" = "5,6"}

$table2 = @{"A" = "2";
            "B" = "5";
            "C" = "7"}

    $newTable = @{}

    function AddToTable($table)
    {
        $table.GetEnumerator() | 
        % {
          if(!$newTable.ContainsKey($_.Key)) {$newTable.Add($_.Key, $_.Value)}
          else {$newTable[$_.Key] += ",$($_.Value)"}
          $newTable[$_.Key] = @($newTable[$_.Key].Split(",") | Get-Unique | Sort-Object) -Join "," 
        }
    }

    AddToTable($table1)
    AddToTable($table2)
```